# Ignoring the first row but still printing it during pattern matching using AWK

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I have a straight-forward problem. If an element in the first column (ID) of "file" matches with an element of first column (ID) of "subfile", the matched element of "file" should be replaced by the corresponding element of second column (i.e by Symbol) of "subfile".

The following code works fine, but considers the first element of second column (ie. A) as first element of first column. Therefore, during pattern matching and omits it from final output, and shifts all elements one cell forward leaving the last cell blank.

I presume that the possible solution would be to ignore the first row. Any suggestions please.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} {$1=a[$1]}1' OFS="\t" subfile file
```

file

```
             A               B                C
204639_at    1.4063964497   1.9690376378    -0.5856006063
209027_s_at -0.6184167971  -0.3803235873     0.6532643621
224864_at    0.9290801469   0.0020026866    -1.2993653537
224637_at    0.4688503882  -0.137487333     -0.453195703
226482_s_at -0.0615034202   0.4300315287    -0.6852205341
```

Subfile

```
204639_at   ADA
209027_s_at ABI1
224864_at   SRA1
224637_at   OST4
226482_s_at TSTD1
```

Output Obtained:

```
      B             C   
ADA   1.4063964497  1.9690376378  -0.5856006063
ABI1 -0.6184167971 -0.3803235873   0.6532643621
SRA1  0.9290801469  0.0020026866  -1.2993653537
OST4  0.4688503882 -0.137487333   -0.453195703
TSTD1 -0.0615034202 0.4300315287  -0.6852205341
```

**Output Needed**

```
      A              B                C
ADA   1.4063964497  1.9690376378  -0.5856006063
ABI1 -0.6184167971 -0.3803235873   0.6532643621
SRA1  0.9290801469  0.0020026866  -1.2993653537
OST4  0.4688503882 -0.137487333   -0.453195703
TSTD1 -0.0615034202 0.4300315287  -0.6852205341
```

Comment: Obviously as A is the first field on the first row ? I have a feeling that you dont actually know what the code you are using does. Try `FNR>1{$1=a[$1]}1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks that there is a match and if not then print the value that is currently there.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} a[$1]{$1=a[$1]}1' OFS="\t" subfile file
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question at all, and I can't even see GSM155673  anywhere in it. However, if, as you suggest, ignoring the first line of one of your input files will help, you could try this to delete line 1:

```
awk '{...}' subfile <(sed 1d file)
```

Or, if you don't like bash process substitution, you can ignore it within `awk` by adding this as the very first part of your script:

```
FNR==1 && NR>1 {print; next}
```

Comment: I think he wants to include the first line but the also keep the `A`